# Is there any way to prevent default golang program finish

Tags: go, websocket

I have a server working with websocket connections and a database. Some users can connect by sockets, so I need to increment their "online" in db; and at the moment of their disconnection I also decrement their "online" field in db. But in case the server breaks down I use a local variable replica map[string]int of users online. So I need to postpone the server shutdown until it completes a database request that decrements all users "online" in accordance with my variable replica, because at this way socket connection doesnt send default "close" event.

I have found a package github.com/xlab/closer that handles some system calls and can do some action before program finished, but my database request doesnt work in this way (code below)

```
func main() {
  ...
  // trying to handle program finish event
  closer.Bind(cleanupSocketConnections(&pageHandler))
  ...
}

// function that handles program finish event
func cleanupSocketConnections(p *controllers.PageHandler) func() {
    return func() {
        p.PageService.ResetOnlineUsers()
    }
}

// this map[string]int contains key=userId, value=count of socket connections
type PageService struct {
    Users map[string]int
}

func (p *PageService) ResetOnlineUsers() {
    for userId, count := range p.Users {
        // decrease online of every user in program variable
        InfoService{}.DecreaseInfoOnline(userId, count)
    }
}
```

Maybe I use it incorrectly or may be there is a better way to prevent default program finish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all executing tasks when the server "breaks down" as you said is quite complicated, because breaking down can mean a lot of things and nothing can guarantee clean up functions execution when something goes really bad in your server.

From an engineering point of view (if setting users offline on breakdown is so important), the best would be to have a secondary service, on another server, that receives user connection and disconnection events and ping event, if it receives no updates in a set timeout the service considers your server down and proceeds to set every user offline.

Back to your question, using defer and waiting for termination signals should cover 99% of cases. I commented the code to explain the logic.

```
// AllUsersOffline is called when the program is terminated, it takes a *sync.Once to make sure this function is performed only
// one time, since it might be called from different goroutines.
func AllUsersOffline(once *sync.Once) {
    once.Do(func() {
        fmt.Print("setting all users offline...")
        // logic to set all users offline
    })
}

// CatchSigs catches termination signals and executes f function at the end
func CatchSigs(f func()) {
    cSig := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    // watch for  these signals
    signal.Notify(cSig, syscall.SIGKILL, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGQUIT, syscall.SIGHUP) // these are the termination signals in GNU =>  https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Termination-Signals.html
    // wait for them
    sig := <- cSig
    fmt.Printf("received signal: %s", sig)
    // execute f
    f()
}
func main() {
    /* code */
    // the once is used to make sure AllUsersOffline is performed ONE TIME.
    usersOfflineOnce := &sync.Once{}
    // catch termination signals
    go CatchSigs(func() {
        // when a termination signal is caught execute AllUsersOffline function
        AllUsersOffline(usersOfflineOnce)
    })
    // deferred functions are called even in case of panic events, although execution is not to take for granted (OOM errors etc)
    defer AllUsersOffline(usersOfflineOnce)
    /* code */
    // run server
    err := server.Run()
    if err != nil {
        // error logic here
    }
    // bla bla bla
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to look at ***go routines*** and ***channel***.
*Here something (maybe) useful*:
https://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/02/15/how-to-wait-for-all-goroutines-to-finish-executing-before-continuing/